# Was my answer deleted in error?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

In re my answer in:

[UEFI or Legacy? Which is advised and why?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/647303/uefi-or-legacy-which-is-advised-and-why/647305#647305)

Another user commented that if I had a new question, I should ask it. I did not have a new question. I was attempting to provide some mildly useful info (user used legacy boot, wanted to know if uefi would give him a flawless system, and I reported that mine was). Then a mod deleted the answer.

I can see a case for deleting the answer on grounds of "Does not answer the question" since I didn't use the two things he was worried about (although I now recall that I had another uefi-booted lenovo laptop whose microphone worked fine). If that was the reason, fair enough. But I suspect that the one user thought there was another question in the answer, and the mod didn't actually check that. If so, shouldn't it be restored?

May not be worth doing b/c others have provided better answers than I did.

Answer (score 2):

Your "answer" seems to be a comment. The mod could have converted it into one, but I don't see why they should have, since you have the reputation to post one yourself.

Comment: That's fine. I was confused by the strange comment left by @Pilot6. If the mod had just said "This should be a comment" before deleting it, that would have helped.

Comment: @user3113723 the mod-delete function doesn't offer any auto-comments the way normal-user-deleting (from the review queue) does. That's probably why.

Comment: mods are ordinary users tho. They can write comments too.

Comment: @user3113723 they can, but they are human too and make the occasional oversights.